# zf2 rest api with base authentication

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, zend-framework2, jwt

I would like to create an rest Zf2 api with base authentication. But I can not figure out how authenticate with jwt token. Does anyone have any examples? There is a zf2 module for login ?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-oauth2

Comment: Apigility project as a whole might be a good place to look at for making restful api, but i do not think it provides a way to setup JWT out of the box. Some extra wiring will be needed

Comment: Xerkus, thank you for answare .
My goal is to create a simple login. Client passes to Server header and Payload coded 64, Sever returns the jwt token that the client will use for subsequent calls.

Comment: underlying oauth2 server used by zf-oauth2 module supports that kind of flow, but it needs to be configured for that. https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/jwt-access-tokens/

Comment: and JWT and client cert can be used to authenticate with the help of the jwt-bearer grant https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/jwt-bearer